# Strange Error in Visual C#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, class, picturebox

I'm working in Visual Studio 2013, and coding in C#. Currently, I'm making a Windows Forms application, and have just learned how to properly use classes, methods, and objects, so I'm still a bit rusty.

I just created a new class (Tab), and started writing it. I wanted it to replace some picture boxes that are used in a form called SkinDesigner. Currently, it doesn't do much, but here's the code so far:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SkinPress
{
    class Tab : PictureBox
    {
        public Tab() : base()
        {
            this.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(Tab_MouseClick);
        }

        void Tab_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Also, I have already edited the code in SkinDesigner.Designer.cs. You'll see that I have already used two other classes, Knob and SkinImage, and they have worked just fine. Below is the code.

```
...
this.BButton = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
this.RButton = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
this.SelectButton = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
this.ABButton = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
this.LButton = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
this.MenuButton = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
this.userSkinImageBox = new SkinImage();
this.iPhonePTab = new Tab();
this.iPhoneLTab = new Tab();
this.iPhoneWLTab = new Tab();
this.iPadPTab = new Tab();
this.iPadLTab = new Tab();
this.iPadRPTab = new Tab();
this.iPadRLTab = new Tab();
this.PressSkinButton = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
this.SaveSkinButton = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
...
private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox LButton;
private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox MenuButton;
private SkinImage userSkinImageBox;
private Tab iPhonePTab;
private Tab iPhoneLTab;
private Tab iPhoneWLTab;
private Tab iPadPTab;
private Tab iPadLTab;
private Tab iPadRPTab;
private Tab iPadRLTab;
private Knob AKnob;
private Knob DPadKnob;
private Knob StartKnob;
private Knob BKnob;
private Knob RKnob;
private Knob SelectKnob;
private Knob ABKnob;
private Knob LKnob;
private Knob MenuKnob;
private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox PressSkinButton;
private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox SaveSkinButton;
...
```

After making the Tab class and changing some picture boxes from System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox to Tab, just as I had done with Knob and SkinImage, I decided that I wanted to go back to my SkinDesigner form to work on some code. Upon double clicking on it to open it, I got an error, which can be found at the links below.

Picture 1
 - [image: Picture 1]

Picture 2
 - [image: Picture 2]

I really don't understand why I'm getting this error. If you look at picture 2, you'll see that Visual Studio is treating my controls as variables (at least, from the looks of it, it is). I honestly don't get what the error is in the first place, nor do I have any idea how to resolve it. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please keep your post contained to this site. People will not follow links and download stuff to help you. If your project is too large, make sure you can provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry about that. Couldn't think of any other ways to display the images, since I'm new here, and can only use 2 links in a post. If you'd like, I can post all of the pictures and links without passwords here.

Comment: @GrantWinney The second snippet isn't quite a snippet... I wasn't sure how to show what I had changed in SkinDesigner.Designer.cs. Will edit it and change it to a snippet. Again, sorry for the inconveniences. Thank you for your feedback for next time. :)

Comment: @GrantWinney There we go! Everything is pretty much cleaned up now. Hope that helps, and again, sorry about the earlier inconveniences.

Comment: @Jenguinie In your way (so far I understand) you are using the designer to work on your GUI. In this case I totally recommend NEVER touch the designer files like SkinDesigner.Designer.cs. These files are automatically generated by the designer and you run into a lot of problems if you try to modify these code lines and working in parallel with the designer and these files. (from my experience)

Comment: @user1341210 Good point, it can really mess things up (as it appears it has)! At the same time, currently I'm taking classes in C#, and my instructor taught me that I should edit designer files, if I want to create a control of a type that is one of my own classes, rather than the typical type of a picture box. Sounds like this might be a bit of a sticky situation, based on what you're saying. Also, yes, I am using the designer (the kind that appears as SkinDesigner[Design]) to edit my GUI, if that's what you're referring to. It's the one where you drag and drop controls onto your form.

Comment: @helrich Thanks so much! Do you think you could add the first picture, too?

Comment: @Jenguinie I embedded both pictures, it just formatted them differently I guess because of size difference. I did crop out the non-relevant areas of the pictures. The parts I removed just said "No stack trace available", for anyone wondering.

Comment: @helrich Oh, sorry about that! Yeah, taking a second look at it, it looks like it just cut off part of the first picture for me. Thanks again!

Comment: After actually looking at your question, did you Build the project in between creating your `Tab` class and opening the designer? If not, the project doesn't know it exists yet.

Comment: @helrich Actually, I don't think I did. Would I fix that by undoing my changes in SkinDesigner.Designer.cs, running the program, and then redoing the changes?

Comment: @helrich That was a bit of a silly question. Will try it when I am back home. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I attempted to use the solution suggested by helrich.

> ... did you Build the project in between creating your Tab class and opening the designer? If not, the project doesn't know it exists yet. - helrich
>
> @helrich Actually, I don't think I did. Would I fix that by undoing my changes in SkinDesigner.Designer.cs, running the program, and then redoing the changes? - Jenguinie

Unfortunately, I had no luck. The error persisted; and then, out of nowhere, it changed. Suddenly, my Tab class wasn't the issue; it was my Knob class.

The same day that the problem changed, I had a C# class. I asked my instructor if he knew how to solve the problem, and he attempted to, but nothing worked. Both of us tried to get the error to stop. The weirdest part was that it was off and on: it would be there one moment, and the next it would be gone, though it would come right back again here and there. Eventually, my instructor found a solution: I was passing a string through my constructor, and for some reason, WinForms didn't like that, so it gave me the error. My instructor found another way to pass the string through, rather than using the designer, and the error was gone.

Either way, thank you for all of your help. I really appreciate it.